# ElasticPress Indexing multiple sites

Tags: search

I am using ElasticPress for WordPress and have setup to index multiple separate WordPress sites to a single index ([details here](https://forumone.com/ideas/searching-multiple-wordpress-sites-elasticsearch/))

This has worked and a search on the main site example.com/ does include results from example.com/site2 however the links are not correct.

Instead of linking the post to example.com/site2/post-name it is simply linking as example.com/post-name resulting in a 404.

My question is how can I get the URLs to work correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you've effectively just told ElasticPress to put both sites' data into the same index? And no other changes? You should first look in the index to make sure that the records do show which site they came from, either by site ID or complete URL, else you'll have to add that. It sounds like it's just saving slug. Then you'll have to hook into the code where ElasticPress retrieves data from its index for search results and process the URLs to add sites where necessary. I assume the ForumOne people must have had to do more work, although ElasticPress may have changed what's stored since then too

Comment: Thanks,

And sorry for the delay in this reply. Would you have any idea on where I can set the URL in the plugin or within the theme's functions.php to have this indexed correctly.